# Logical branching with FreeForm Pro?

Tags: solspace-freeform, forms

Has anyone done forms with logical branching in FreeForm? Something like, if somebody selects "Other" from a radio group, show + require an "Other" text field? If there are any examples that'd be a great help.

Or is FreeForm not the right place to start for something like this? Thanks for any ideas.

Answer (score 2):

DevDemon's Forms add-on (http://www.devdemon.com/expressionengine-addons/forms) allows you to have conditional fields which only show if a previous field contains a particular value.

See their video on Vimeo for a demonstration (http://vimeo.com/45418039).

Answer (score 1):

I've done similar over the years and by far the best practice is to ask the variables up front in a faux form. Once the variables are answered load the appropriate and ACTUAL form, where you can GET the default fields (name,address etc) from initial form.

I have also used javascript to hide/show content but obviously doesn't have any fall back with JS disabled and getting around Freeforms 'required' setting means removing it via JS - can be consuming to wire together.

There is nothing native with any form solution from EE or Solspace or others as far as I'm aware.